# Lua script to poke clients in TS3 explanation

Tags: lua, scripting, teamspeak

This is a working TS3 poke script, which pokes all of the users:

```
function pokeall(serverConnectionHandlerID)
 local clients, error = ts3.getClientList(serverConnectionHandlerID)    
  for i=1, #clients do
 local clname, clientNameError = ts3.getClientVariableAsString(serverConnectionHandlerID, clients[i], ts3defs.ClientProperties.CLIENT_NICKNAME)
 ts3.requestClientPoke(serverConnectionHandlerID, clients[i], "Lua Pokeall script :-)")
 --ts3.printMessage(serverConnectionHandlerID, "Poked "..clname.." (id: "..clients[i]..")!")        
end 
end
```

`ts3.printMessage` is a comment now (optional).

This script is working with command: **/lua run pokeall**

I'm new in Lua. I want to understand how this code works.
So here, if i get it correctly:
we have 2 variables `clients` and `clname`. `clients[i]` with `for` it's obviously a loop. It starts  with index 1 (so it's the 2. element). Why not with 0 (i = 0) ?

`clname` gets the user name, i think...

How can i poke a concrete user ?
*(to poke only 1 user with command: /lua run pokeall USER_NICKNAME --> name of the user)*

Enough to change the `clients[i]` to `clname` in `ts3.requestClientPoke` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why not with 0 (i = 0) ?

Because Lua sequences start at index 1 unlike most other programming languages.

> Enough to change the clients[i] to clname in ts3.requestClientPoke ?

You poke a user with its client id, not with its name.